# How to model one-to-one relationship across tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database, data-modeling, rdbms

I have a master table, say `Products`, which has three fields: `product_id`, `product_name` and `product_type`. `product_type` can be `type_1`, `type_2` or `type_3`. Depending on the type, further information about the product can be found ni the tables `Product_type_1`, `Product_type_2` or `Product_type_3` respectively.

Each of the `Product_type_*` tables has a `product_id` that references to the same column in the `Product` table. Is there a way I can ensure that for each row in the `Product` table, there is exactly one row in exactly one of the `Product_type_*` tables? If possible, I would also want to make sure that the row is in the table corresponding to the `product_type`. Let me know if my example is not clear.

Comment: It might help to show some additional information on the fields on these tables.  ON the surface, I am not understanding why you would have a `product_id` field in the `product_type_*` tables.

Comment: `product_type_*` tables would have a `product_id` foreign key which will ensure that the corresponding "parent" object is present in the `Products` table

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1) enforce the rule with a trigger, preventing the insertion of multiple rows in the *type* tables and requiring a row in the *type* table that corresponds to the product_type value.

2) using three different ids and then relying on "plain ol'" foreign keys.

I prefer #2.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Following query will give you 'product_id' which do not have corresponding records in any one of the Product_type*..

```
Select P.product_id
From Products P
Left Outer Join Product_type_1 PT1 ON P.product_id = PT1.product_id

Left Outer Join Product_type_2 PT2 ON P.product_id = PT2.product_id

Left Outer Join Product_type_3 PT3 ON P.product_id = PT3.product_id

Where (PT1.product_id IS NULL AND PT2.product_id IS NULL AND PT3.product_id IS NULL)
```

Let me know if this helps in solving your problem...

Answer (score 0):

If the structures of three `Product_type_X` tables are the same, then I'd suggest you to use one child table `Product_type`, just add foreign key: `Product_type`.`product_id` ->  `Products`.`product_id`. So, it will be one-to-many relation.

Comment: The structures of `Product_type_X` tables are different. All the properties common to all product types are captured in the `Product` table

Comment: Then this variant of solving the problem will not help you;-) In this case you should create primary keys in those three tables - PRIMARY KEY (product_id), and also you can add three foreign keys to those tables, so there will be three one-to-one relations.